# registering binary content using document API

Tags: java, marshalling, orientdb

Using orientdb 3.0.x documentation, I'm trying to store some binary data into database, with the unmarshalling approach

```
ODocument save(OrientGraph graph, byte[] content) {

    ODatabaseDocument rawGraph = graph.getRawGraph();
    rawGraph.declareIntent(new OIntentMassiveInsert());

    List<ORID> chunks = new ArrayList<>();
    InputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(new ByteArrayInputStream(content));

    while (in.available() > 0) {
        final ORecordBytes chunk = new ORecordBytes();
        chunk.fromInputStream(in, BLOCK_SIZE);
        rawGraph.save(chunk);
        chunks.add(chunk.getIdentity());
    }

    ODocument record = new ODocument();
    record.field(Resource.RESOURCE_FIELD_CHUNKS, chunks);
    log.debug("Splitted file to {}", chunks.size());

    rawGraph.save(record);

    rawGraph.declareIntent(null);

    return record;
}
```

Note that I'm using `graph.getRawGraph()` to switch from Graph API to Object API connection.

**My problem :**
This code throws the following error

> `com.orientechnologies.orient.core.exception.ODatabaseException: Cannot save (1) document #-1:-3{chunks:[1]} v0: no class or cluster defined`

when calling `graph.commit()` afterwards

**Orientdb version** : 3.0.2

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to create a new vertex class to store the document gathering chunks.

```
CREATE CLASS BinaryContent EXTENDS V
```

Then replace

```
ODocument record = new ODocument("BinaryContent");
```

in the code given in the question above (of course `BinaryContent` can be replaced by anything)